# How to increase badge count when a button clicked ios?

Tags: ios, increment, badge

In myapp i am having tab button items 
1. 0-10pounds
2. 10-50pounds
3. Partial truck buttons.

if i click 0-10pounds item i have to show a badge increased to 1 for the same item. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If i understand it correctly you are using uitabbar so you need to do: 
self.navigationController.tabBarItem.badgeValue = @"{your_value}";

Comment: I have to increase value for every click @Ran Hassid

Comment: You need to increase the value of the tab item that you clicked on ?

Comment: Create a counter to keep track then + the counter value and assign it to the badgeValue as @RanHassid mentioned

Comment: @Vignesh - you need to increase it only if the item was not selected and then the user selected it or you increase it anyway ?

Comment: @RanHassid badge count have to increase only if user selects the button.

Comment: So in that case you have 2 options: 
1. Call the above code  in viewWillAppear method of your view controller and increase the badge
2. Use UITabBarControllerDelegate and do it in the - tabBarController:didSelectViewController: delegate method (the recommended way from my POV)